# Unity how to set Off mesh link speed

Tags: unity, ai, navmesh

How can I set agent's speed on off mesh link? I want it to look like a jump, but now it looks like it was in slow motion.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an Update or FixedUpdate function check when the agent is on an off-mesh link, and modify its speed in response, as shown here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class LinkSpeedScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public bool linking;
    public float origSpeed;

    // just change linkspeed to alter off mesh link traverse speed;
    public float linkSpeed;

    void Start()
    {
        origSpeed = agent.speed;
        linking = false;        
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (agent.isOnOffMeshLink && linking == false)
        {
            linking = true;
            agent.speed = agent.speed * linkSpeed;
        }
        else if (agent.isOnNavMesh && linking == true)
        {
            linking = false;
            agent.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            agent.speed = origSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work with my NavMeshAgent settings.

Answer (score 0):

This [unity forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/navmesh-off-mesh-link-velocity-control.540983/#post-3567037) suggests handling the traversing yourself.

> ```
> if(agent.isOnOffMeshLink && !MoveAcrossNavMeshesStarted){
>     StartCoRoutine(MoveAcrossNavMeshLink());
>     MoveAcrossNavMeshesStarted=true;
> }
>
> IEnumerator MoveAcrossNavMeshLink()
> {
>         OffMeshLinkData data = agent.currentOffMeshLinkData;
>         agent.updateRotation = false;
>
>         Vector3 startPos = agent.transform.position;
>         Vector3 endPos = data.endPos + Vector3.up * agent.baseOffset;
>         float duration = (endPos-startPos).magnitude/agent.Velocity.magnitude;
>         float t = 0.0f;
>         float tStep = 1.0f/duration;
>         while(t<1.0f){
>             transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos,endPos,t);
>             agent.destination = transform.position;
>             t+=tStep*Time.deltaTime;
>             yield return null;
>         }
>         transform.position = endPos;
>         agent.updateRotation = true;
>         agent.CompleteOffMeshLink();
>         MoveAcrossNavMeshesStarted= false;
>
> }
> ```

To make it look like a jump, you could

1. lerp between the two positions and play a jump animation on a child node of the hierarchy
2. calculate the y-position yourself, e.g.
   `s = 0,5 · a · t2 + vo · t + s0`
   with `vo` being the initial velocity and `s0` being the inital position. Use this formula for y.